# Organizando ordem do Mês em um array php

Tags: php, array

Usei a função abaixo para organizar as ordens dos meses em ordem crescente, funciona perfeitamente, porém ela perde as chaves, quando cria o novo `array` organizado, as chaves iniciam do 0 (*zero*) novamente

`Array` desordenado:

> `Array ( [39] => agosto [40] => agosto [41] => agosto [42] => agosto [43] => agosto [44] => agosto [45] => agosto [46] => agosto [48] => agosto [71] => novembro [69] => novembro [70] => novembro [64] => outubro [65] => outubro [66] => outubro [68] => outubro [49] => setembro [51] => setembro [52] => setembro [53] => setembro [54] => setembro [55] => setembro [56] => setembro [57] => setembro [59] => setembro [60] => setembro [62] => setembro )`

`Array` ordenado, após passar pela função abaixo, porém perdendo as chaves:

> `Array ( [0] => agosto [1] => agosto [2] => agosto [3] => agosto [4] => agosto [5] => agosto [6] => agosto [7] => agosto [8] => agosto [9] => setembro [10] => setembro [11] => setembro [12] => setembro [13] => setembro [14] => setembro [15] => setembro [16] => setembro [17] => setembro [18] => setembro [19] => setembro [20] => outubro [21] => outubro [22] => outubro [23] => outubro [24] => novembro [25] => novembro [26] => novembro )`

e abaixo a função utilizada:

```
$sort = array('Janeiro', 'janeiro','Fevereiro', 
              'fevereiro','Março', 'março','Abril', 
              'abril','Maio', 'maio','Junho', 'junho',
              'Julho', 'julho','Agosto', 'Agosto',
              'Setembro', 'setembro','Outubro', 'outubro',
              'Novembro', 'novembro','Dezembro', 'dezembro');

usort($teste,
       function($value1, $value2) use ($sort) {
           return array_search($value1,$sort) > array_search($value2,$sort);
       }
);
```

Minha pergunta é, como eu faço essa ordenação em ordem crescente dos meses sem perder as chaves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver apenas trocando o 'usort', pelo 'uasort', classifica com base no meu array base ($sort), porém mantendo as chaves.

```
$sort = array('Janeiro', 'janeiro','Fevereiro', 
              'fevereiro','Março', 'março','Abril', 
              'abril','Maio', 'maio','Junho', 'junho',
              'Julho', 'julho','Agosto', 'Agosto',
              'Setembro', 'setembro','Outubro', 'outubro',
              'Novembro', 'novembro','Dezembro', 'dezembro');

uasort($teste,
       function($value1, $value2) use ($sort) {
           return array_search($value1,$sort) > array_search($value2,$sort);
       }
);
```